# How to prevent class instance from being modified?

Tags: swift

**Question:**

Is there a way to prevent a class instance (reference type) from being modified ?

**Reason:**

The reason for asking this is because when a reference to a class instance is passed to a function, the function might unintentionally modify the instance.

**Note:**
Using let or private function / property prevents complete access to the outside world. The question is how to prevent a normal class instance from being modified by a function.

I was hoping for something like what is available in C++.

**C++ code equivalent of what I was requesting:**

```
const CA * ca1; //This is C++ and was hoping for something like this in swift
```

**Code:**

```
class CA {
    var x1 : Int = 10

    func modify() {
        x1 = 99
    }
}


let ca1 = CA()

ca1.x1 = 30 //Is there a way I can prevent ca1 from this from being modified ?

ca1.modify() //Is there a way I can prevent ca1 from this from being modified ?



//This function should not modify the CA instance
func display(#ca : CA) {

    ca.x1 = 30 //Is there a way I can prevent ca from this from being modified ?

    ca.modify() //Is there a way I can prevent ca from this from being modified ?

    println("ca.x1 = \(ca.x1)")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the property have an internal (the default access) getter and private setter. This way, other classes can read the value but they cannot modify it, only your class can modify it.

```
class Test {
    private(set) var x1 : Int = 0

    func increaseX1() {
        x1++
    }
}

let t = Test()
print(t.x1) // 0
t.increaseX1()
print(t.x1) // 1
t.x1 = 2 // error: Cannot assign to 'x1' in 't'
```

Note that you will be able to assign `t.x1` if you try this in the playground since "private" isn't totally private in Swift: code within the *same source file* can access it.

To make the getter public instead of internal, you'd do:

```
public private(set) var x1 : Int = 0
// or:
private(set) public var x1 : Int = 0
```

**Edit:** Now that I understand your intention, here's one way to work around the problem that Swift doesn't support the `const` mechanism of making objects read-only in the way C++ does: create a helper struct that only has `let` constants and provide a function that returns such an helper. I'd only use that with classes that have only few instance variables, though (you wouldn't want to do that with a class that has dozens):

```
struct ConstCA {
    let x1 : Int
}

class CA {
    var x1 : Int = 10

    func modify() {
        x1 = 99
    }

    func getConstCA() -> ConstCA {
        return ConstCA(x1 : x1)
    }
}

func display(#ca : ConstCA) {
    // Can only read `x1` but cannot modify it.
}
```

Comment: I want modify() and x1 to be modified by other instances. I just don't want the function display modifying it.

Comment: Oooh, now I get it. There is no way to achieve that since Swift doesn't have the equivalent `const` mechanism from C++. The language is still in flux, so maybe the team might add it in the future (now that I finally understand what you want to do, I agree that it's a very valuable tool). But for now, the language doesn't support "constifying" an object.

Comment: I suppose that is the only possible solution as of now. Really wish they bring mutating functions to classes !!

Answer (score 1):

```
class CA {
```

If you make the `var` a `let` then neither `modify()` can change it.

```
    let x1: Int = 10 // wrong, can't be modified neither internally.
```

Correct solution would be to make `x1` `private`, now you can access it only from here. If you try to access `x1` elsewhere in the project you'll get the error: `'CA' does not have a member named 'x1'`

```
    private var x1: Int = 10 // correct, class objects can change it, instances can not.

    func modify() {
        x1 = 99
    }

}
```

If you don't want to access neither the `modify()` function from your class instance variable, just `private` that too.

Also for your reference I find that this article explains Access Control in a very concise and simple way: [Access Control in Swift](http://www.codingexplorer.com/access-control-swift/)

Comment: I think by "instance" you actually mean "other classes". An instance is a concrete object of a class. For example, `let c = CA()`: here, `c` references an instance of class `CA`.

Comment: By instance I mean the instantiation of the class, you create a class and to use it you have to call init on it, that's what the () are for, calling init without an argument.

Comment: Yeah, so you do understand what an instance is, but this sentence: _"If you don't want Instances of your class to access neither the modify() function, just private that too."_ That just doesn't make sense. Instances of a class can always access their variables and functions. So what do you want to express with that sentence and the comment _"class objects can change it, instances can not"_? What do you mean with "class objects"? Your solution is correct (but might be missing a getter, if required), but your wording is very confusing.

Comment: You create an instance of CA, now you can use CA through the instance variable. You can not access private properties/funcs/etc.. using the instance variable. I'm gonna rephrase it. Thank you for pointing out that my wording created confusion.

Comment: I want modify() and x1 to be modified by other instances. I just don't want the function display modifying it.

Comment: Does this mean that you want `ca1.x1` to be modifiable via your class instance variable? i.e.: `ca1.x1 = 30` but not from just the function display? I'm sorry I ask, but I really don't understand clearly what you mean here, the question description comments say otherwise.

Comment: changing the value of `x1` and invoking the function `modify` should be allowed for certain instances of `CA1`. In C++ you could create `const CA*` . Now this pointer to `CA1` wouldn't allow that the instance of `CA1` to be modified. So for the display function i can just have the parameter type to be `const CA*`. I wanted something like that. I suppose Swift doesn't have mutating functions for classes. I wish they include that !

Answer (score 0):

You can always use let to create constant that cannot be modified

```
let x1 : Int = 10
```

or you can implement it with getter:

```
var x1 : Int {
    get {
        return 10
    }
}
```

By using this you'll be able to access getter only and thus you'll not be able to modify variable.

Comment: I want modify() and x1 to be modified by other instances. I just don't want the function display modifying it.